# Como puedo hacer una consulta de jerarquía en la misma tabla? Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta SQL en Oracle. Donde a partir del campo `login = 337253` de la tabla `interlocutor`, pueda traer la jerarquía; si `login = '80'` o si `clase = 0`  aquí se acaba la jerarquía.

La idea es: "Encontrar al mas anciano a partir del mas joven".

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de hacer la consulta de la siguiente manera, pero no tengo una idea clara de como hacerlo.

```
    with jerarquia (
owner, login, nombre, clase) as (
select owner, login, nombre, clase from interlocutor where login = '337253'
union all select in.owner, in.login, in.nombre, in.clase
from interlocutor in join jerarquia on jerarquia.owner = in.owner)
select * from jerarquia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Con la cláusula **START WITH** identificamos el registro inicial, es decir, el lugar desde el que empieza nuestro árbol, y con la cláusula **CONNECT BY** PRIOR, indicamos las columnas entre las que establece la relación registro padre - registro hijo.

Si lo que queremos es subir en la jerarquía en lugar de bajar, entonces debemos cambiar el orden de los registros en la cláusula **CONNECT BY PRIOR**"

Solución:

```
select owner, login, nombre, clase from interlocutor
                    start with login = 337253
                    connect by prior owner = login
```

Fuente: https://www.plsql.biz/2012/10/consultas-jerarquicas-plsql-start-with-connect-by-prior.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Select level, nombre, otros_campos 
From tabla
Connect by owner = prior login;
```

La **cláusula connect by** es la que permite hacer **consultas jerárquicas** en **Oracle** y en el **select** pongo el **modificador level** que indica los **niveles jerárquicos** qué hay desde el registro inicial hasta el último, ejemplo: **Abuelo**, **Padre**, **Hijo**. **Entre Abuelo y Padre el nivel es 1 y entre abuelo e hijo el nivel es 2**.

Te recomiendo que investigues más sobre la **cláusula [connect by](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)**, espero te sirva el ejemplo que puse, adáptalo a tu código.