# Ordenar intartecaladamente registros padres seguidos de sus hijos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

En la siguiente imagen muestro una serie de registros de una tabla en mi base de datos donde los registros se diferencian por dos campos por el padre y el nivel.
Me gustaría hacer un **SELECT**  que me ayude a ordenar los registros de la siguiente manera.

-**Registro Padre**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**
-**Registro Padre**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**
---**Registro hijo**

Básicamente tener los padres seguidos de los hijos correspondientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si exista un **ORDER BY** donde pudiera poner alguna condición u operación que me permita hacer dicho ordenamiento.

Los padres son aquellos que en la columna padre tienen el numero 0 y aquellos que tengan el valor distinto de 0 son los hijos o también los padres son aquellos que tienen en la columna nivel el valor de 1 y los hijos son los que tienen el nivel con valor numero 2.

`SELECT * FROM proy_arbol_cursos ORDER BY FIELD(id, padre) DESC;`

Este es el resultado de esta consulta, el único detalle es que el registro 15 debería ir después del registro dos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguna consejo se los agradecería mucho.

Definición de la tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400375/como-puedo-hacer-una-consulta-de-jerarqu%c3%ada-en-la-misma-tabla-oracle-sql/400419#400419   revisa esto, puede serte util

Comment: Hola! Recuerda siempre que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Siempre puedes revisar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Intentar algo y que falle siempre es mejor que traer una pregunta sin código hecho por uno mismo :)

Comment: Lo otro: para preguntas de BD en la que buscas una consulta SQL, procura siempre añadir la definición de las tablas a usar (para saber el tipo de dato en las columnas) y datos de prueba (los que pusiste están bien) junto con la salida esperada (qué debería mostrar la consulta).

Comment: Discúlpame, espero que las modificaciones sean lo que tu mencionas.

Comment: Debes ordenar por id primero, luego por padre Field(id, padre) para que mantenga el orden.

Comment: Obtengo el mismo Resultado, el registro 15 sigue apareciendo abajo.

Answer (score 1):

Es un lío porque la tabla tiene una relación consigo misma y eso podría representarse usando un JOIN de la tabla (alias t1) con ella misma (alias t2) en `t1.id = t2.padre`. Lo malo es que eso no incluiría los registros de nivel 0 (porque no son padres de sí mismos).

Esto creo que tampoco funcionaría si tienes más de un subnivel.

Sin modificar los datos, creo que es más fácil operar sobre el resultset en el código que ejecute la consulta e ir buscando los que tengan idPadre = X.

Answer (score 1):

La forma de como hacerlo esta resuelta en

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

To do this you need to do it with recursive selects for mysql 5 and earlier they are done one way and for mysql 8 they are done another way... here is the link

¡click [here](https://www.wake-up-neo.net/es/mysql/como-crear-una-consulta-recursiva-jerarquica-de-mysql/1042885356/) !

```
id | name        | parent_id
19 | category1   | 0
20 | category2   | 19
21 | category3   | 20
22 | category4   | 21
```

Mysql 8

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             parent_id
  from       products
  where      parent_id = 19
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.name,
             p.parent_id
  from       products p
  inner join cte
          on p.parent_id = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

before mysql 8

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '19') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! El idioma del sitio es el español. Además, las partes más relevantes del enlace que proporcionas deben ir en la propia respuesta: los enlaces pueden romperse, y futuros lectores no podrían beneficiarse del mismo. Lee [answer].

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A veces nos complicamos demasiado siendo que las respuestas son mas sencillas de lo que esperábamos;  lo que tu necesitas es mapear el orden en base a un campo y luego por otro y eso en MySQL lo puedes hacer mediante la sentencia FIELD():

> SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY FIELD(1,2....) DESC;

En el cual la consulta realizará el orden por el primer campo que retorne nuestra consulta y luego por el otro, no obstante también puedes hacer el ordenamiento a través de los nombres de los campos resultantes

> SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabla ORDER BY FIELD (campo2, campo1 ....) DESC;

para tu caso quedaría:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY FIELD(id, padre) DESC;
```

Espero te sea útil esta respuesta te dejo un link con información mas detallada.

[Tutotial ORDER BY MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/)

Comment: Pues no me da el resultado esperado, pero agradezco la informacion amplio el panorama, creo que tendre que ordenar a nivel codigo